# Matching the beginning characters in a LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose in my like clause for my query, i would like to match all records that begins with the characters `'Harris'` in my specified column. But their can also be names such as `'Harrison'` that I would also like to match. How would I go about finding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from MyTable
where somecol LIKE 'Harris%'
```